# How to close Amplify PR preview website once the new commit is pushed?

Tags: cypress, aws-amplify, circleci

I'm setting Amplify for reviewing PRs in the deployed website and also I have CircleCI with Cypress tests. The current structure of my project is once a PR is raised, Amplify deployment starts and at the same time and CircleCI runs Cypress when Amplify's preview website is accessible. The accessibility check is done with the `wait-on` command.

It works perfectly fine when I raise a PR, but if I continue to push new commits, there comes a problem. That is, the Cypress test runs on the Amplify website with the previous version of commits. This is because, from my understanding, Amplify website doesn't shut down until the new deployment is done, so the previous version website is available while the new deployment is in the provisioning and building stages.

I think the best way would be to move the Cypress tests to Amplify, instead of CircleCI which depends on Amplify's status. But I want to know if there's a simpler way to achieve this.